# Map each char in a string to a 1 or a 0

Tags: haskell

```
mapbinary :: String -> [Int]
```

I am trying to use this function to convert a string to a list with `1`'s and `0`'s.
My thinking is that I should be mapping each char that returns true with isLetter to 1, and all others to 0.

I've been trying something like `map (isLetter x)`, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Can you show your full attempt? EDIT: And the error, if any.

Comment: [ d | e <- "abc.def.h i j", d <- if elem e ['a'..'z'] then [1] else [0]] ....
[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your are using `Data.Char.isLetter`. In that case, your are almost right, you just have to convert your `Bool` into `Int` using `fromEnum`

```
mapbinary :: String -> [Int]
mapbinary x = map (fromEnum . isLetter) x  -- Point-free-versión = map $ fromEnum . isLetter
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.

```
map      :: (a    -> b    ) -> [a] -> [b]
isLetter ::  Char -> Bool
```

You can combine these immediately to make:

```
map isLetter :: [Char] -> [Bool]
map isLetter :: String -> [Bool] -- equivalently
```

This is very close to what you're looking for, the only difference is that it returns `True` and `False`, instead of `1` and `0` respectively. So you'll also need to do something about that.

We can define a function `boolToInt` that does this:

```
boolToInt :: Bool -> Int
boolToInt False = 0
boolToInt True = 1
```

However, it happens that the Prelude function [`fromEnum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum) does the same thing in this case.

```
map fromEnum . map isLetter :: String -> [Int]
```

Or, equivalently:

```
map (fromEnum.isLetter) :: String -> [Int]
```